# Any suggestion on getting the Windows IP address of a machine in C++ (using Visual Studio 2019)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, ip-address

I have put together a program using the sample program from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo

However, the problem I face is that when I list the Adapter descriptions and adapter IP addresses, all the IPv4 addresses (including the Virtualbox addresses) show up. We are interested in the Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 IP address.

On executing the program, below are the adapter descriptions, IP addresses that show up:

```
    ComboIndex:     17
    Adapter Name:   {E783F44-FB13-4D75-962E-BB5DE229F1B1}
    Adapter Desc:   VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
    Adapter Addr:   0A-00-28-00-00-13
    Index:  19
    Type:   Ethernet
    IP Address:     192.168.36.1
    IP Mask:        255.255.255.0
    Gateway:        0.0.0.0
    ***
    DHCP Enabled: No
    Have Wins: No

    ComboIndex:     5
    Adapter Name:   {3A58A814-B840-4951-9302-6D2FDB404FF3}
    Adapter Desc:   Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
    Adapter Addr:   C8-24-58-50-47-32
    Index:  5
    Type:   Unknown type 71
    IP Address:     192.168.0.106
    IP Mask:        255.255.255.0
    Gateway:        192.168.0.1
    ***
    DHCP Enabled: Yes
      DHCP Server:  192.168.0.1
      Lease Obtained: Tue Jan 19 17:17:51 2021
      Lease Expires:  Fri Apr 17 00:14:00 1970
    Have Wins: No

    ComboIndex:     18
    Adapter Name:   {FB92F018-6F10-47D3-96D6-010DAF3DDEB8}
    Adapter Desc:   Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
    Adapter Addr:   C8-24-58-50-46-34
    Index:  18
    Type:   Unknown type 71
    IP Address:     0.0.0.0
    IP Mask:        0.0.0.0
    Gateway:        0.0.0.0
    ***
    DHCP Enabled: Yes
      DHCP Server:
      Lease Obtained: Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970
      Lease Expires:  Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970
    Have Wins: No

    ComboIndex:     12
    Adapter Name:   {7CD8BFA9-ACEB-48CB-A241-D3CA9342EEF4}
    Adapter Desc:   Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
    Adapter Addr:   CA-22-58-51-45-35
    Index:  12
    Type:   Unknown type 71
    IP Address:     0.0.0.0
    IP Mask:        0.0.0.0
    Gateway:        0.0.0.0
    ***
    DHCP Enabled: Yes
      DHCP Server:
      Lease Obtained: Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970
      Lease Expires:  Invalid Argument to _localtime32_s
    Have Wins: No
```

Hence, to read ONLY the systems' IP address I modified the program to search for a string other than 'Microsoft' or 'Virtual' (to eliminate adapter descriptions).

This works on my system. But I'm not convinced that this is the best way to get a machine's IP address.

Any suggestion, on how I can modify the logic to get the IP address of ANY system this program is executed on, is highly appreciated!

Below is the program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

using namespace std;

/* Note: could also use malloc() and free() */

string getMachineIPAddr()
{
    /* Declare and initialize variables */
    vector<string> adapterName;
    vector<string> adapterDesc;
    vector<string> adapterIpAddr;

    int count = 0;

    // It is possible for an adapter to have multiple
    // IPv4 addresses, gateways, and secondary WINS servers
    // assigned to the adapter. 
    //
    // Note that this sample code only prints out the 
    // first entry for the IP address/mask, and gateway, and
    // the primary and secondary WINS server for each adapter. 

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo;
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = NULL;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    UINT i;

    /* variables used to print DHCP time info */
    struct tm newtime;
    char buffer[32];
    errno_t error;
    string err_str = "Err: Exiting function!";

    ULONG ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);
    pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)MALLOC(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    if (pAdapterInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
        return err_str;
    }
    // Make an initial call to GetAdaptersInfo to get
    // the necessary size into the ulOutBufLen variable
    if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        FREE(pAdapterInfo);
        pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)MALLOC(ulOutBufLen);
        if (pAdapterInfo == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
            return err_str;
        }
    }

    if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == NO_ERROR) {
        pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
        while (pAdapter) {
            printf("\tComboIndex: \t%d\n", pAdapter->ComboIndex);
            printf("\tAdapter Name: \t%s\n", pAdapter->AdapterName);
            printf("\tAdapter Desc: \t%s\n", pAdapter->Description);
            printf("\tAdapter Addr: \t");

            adapterName.push_back(pAdapter->AdapterName);
            adapterDesc.push_back(pAdapter->Description);
            adapterIpAddr.push_back(pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String);

            for (i = 0; i < pAdapter->AddressLength; i++) {
                if (i == (pAdapter->AddressLength - 1))
                    printf("%.2X\n", (int)pAdapter->Address[i]);
                else
                    printf("%.2X-", (int)pAdapter->Address[i]);
            }
            printf("\tIndex: \t%d\n", pAdapter->Index);
            printf("\tType: \t");
            switch (pAdapter->Type) {
            case MIB_IF_TYPE_OTHER:
                printf("Other\n");
                break;
            case MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET:
                printf("Ethernet\n");
                break;
            case MIB_IF_TYPE_TOKENRING:
                printf("Token Ring\n");
                break;
            case MIB_IF_TYPE_FDDI:
                printf("FDDI\n");
                break;
            case MIB_IF_TYPE_PPP:
                printf("PPP\n");
                break;
            case MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK:
                printf("Lookback\n");
                break;
            case MIB_IF_TYPE_SLIP:
                printf("Slip\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown type %ld\n", pAdapter->Type);
                break;
            }

            printf("\tIP Address: \t%s\n",
                pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String);
            printf("\tIP Mask: \t%s\n", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpMask.String);

            printf("\tGateway: \t%s\n", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String);
            printf("\t***\n");

            if (pAdapter->DhcpEnabled) {
                printf("\tDHCP Enabled: Yes\n");
                printf("\t  DHCP Server: \t%s\n",
                    pAdapter->DhcpServer.IpAddress.String);

                printf("\t  Lease Obtained: ");
                /* Display local time */
                error = _localtime32_s(&newtime, (__time32_t*)&pAdapter->LeaseObtained);
                if (error)
                    printf("Invalid Argument to _localtime32_s\n");
                else {
                    // Convert to an ASCII representation 
                    error = asctime_s(buffer, 32, &newtime);
                    if (error)
                        printf("Invalid Argument to asctime_s\n");
                    else
                        /* asctime_s returns the string terminated by \n\0 */
                        printf("%s", buffer);
                }

                printf("\t  Lease Expires:  ");
                error = _localtime32_s(&newtime, (__time32_t*)&pAdapter->LeaseExpires);
                if (error)
                    printf("Invalid Argument to _localtime32_s\n");
                else {
                    // Convert to an ASCII representation 
                    error = asctime_s(buffer, 32, &newtime);
                    if (error)
                        printf("Invalid Argument to asctime_s\n");
                    else
                        /* asctime_s returns the string terminated by \n\0 */
                        printf("%s", buffer);
                }
            }
            else
                printf("\tDHCP Enabled: No\n");

            if (pAdapter->HaveWins) {
                printf("\tHave Wins: Yes\n");
                printf("\t  Primary Wins Server:    %s\n",
                    pAdapter->PrimaryWinsServer.IpAddress.String);
                printf("\t  Secondary Wins Server:  %s\n",
                    pAdapter->SecondaryWinsServer.IpAddress.String);
            }
            else
                printf("\tHave Wins: No\n");
            pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("GetAdaptersInfo failed with error: %d\n", dwRetVal);

    }
    
    // THIS IS CODE TO ELIMINATE ADAPTERS WITH 'MICROSOFT' OR 'VIRTUAL' 
    // IN THE ADAPTER DESCRIPTIONS
    vector<string>::iterator it = adapterDesc.begin();
    vector<string>::iterator it2 = adapterIpAddr.begin();

    string compareStr1 = "Microsoft";
    string compareStr2 = "Virtual";
    string outAdapterDesc = "";
    string outAdapterIPAddr = "";

    for (it = adapterDesc.begin(), it2 = adapterIpAddr.begin(); it != adapterDesc.end(); it++, it2++)
    {
        printf("*it: %s\n", it->c_str());
        printf("*it2: %s\n", it2->c_str());
         
        size_t found = it->find("Microsoft");
        size_t found2 = it->find("Virtual");

        if ((found == string::npos) || (found2 == string::npos))
        {
            outAdapterDesc = *it;
            outAdapterIPAddr = *it2;
        }
    }

    printf("outAdapterDesc: %s\n", outAdapterDesc.c_str());
    printf("outAdapterIPAddr: %s\n", outAdapterIPAddr.c_str());

    if (pAdapterInfo)
        FREE(pAdapterInfo);

    return outAdapterIPAddr;
}


int __cdecl main()
{
    string machineIPAddr = getMachineIPAddr();
    cout << "machineIPAddr: " << getMachineIPAddr() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Stay far, far away from `#define` in C++. In this case just write regular functions instead. If you want to have wrappers for simplicity that's fine, the compiler will optimize the details away as necessary. That being said, it's far from clear why you're using a "custom" `malloc` in a C++ program when `new` is like right there. If you need to use regular `malloc`, just use that.

Comment: You can look at the "gateway" address. Local or disconnected interfaces will have zeros for this. There is still the possibility that a system has multiple active network connections, though.

Comment: @ tadman: Thanks for your input, I had used the program from MS documentation direct. But, otherwise, I shall keep your tip in mind.

Comment: @ 1201ProgramAlarm: Ah! I see your point! Thank you! But again, looks like you said, a system may have multiple n/w connections..

Comment: On Windows XP and later:  Use the [GetAdaptersAddresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) function instead of `GetAdaptersInfo`. Both `GetAdaptersInfo` and `GetAdaptersAddresses` need to traverse all low-level network interface tables. In other words, you still need to set flag to filter what you need. But `GetAdaptersAddresses` can provide more options.

Comment: @Strive Sun - MSFT: Thank you! I'll try that out!

Answer (score 0):

Call `GetBestRoute` to get a route to a relevant IP address, and check the resulting `MIB_IPFORWARDROW::dwForwardIfIndex` interface index. Google's DNS at 8.8.8.8 is a reasonable choice. You're not actually connecting, just checking what would happen if you tried. Your VirtualBox interface won't be able to reach 8.8.8.8, but a VPN might.

Comment: Sure, let me give it a try. Thank you for your input!